# Set notation help

Tags: relations

I'm working on this questions:

Let $A= \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$. Let $R$ be the relation defined by $xRy$ if and only if $y=-x$. Let $S$ be the relation defined by $xSy$ if and only if $y = |x|$

Whilst I've figured out most of the question, what I don't understand is what $y = |x|$ is supposed to mean.

I know that $|A|$ means the number of elements in set $A$ (cardinality) but does it means the same for an element. I'm a little bit confused and not sure if I'm interpreting this correctly.

Comment: Being *numbers*.I suppose it means "absolute value", e.g. : |-2|=2.

Comment: Oh...I never thought of it that way!